# ERROR in calling UTL_MAIL procedures

Tags: plsql, utl-mail

I am trying to send mails through UTL_MAIL.
where I used below code:

```
declare
v_sender VARCHAR2(30);
v_recipients VARCHAR2(60);
v_subj VARCHAR2(20);
v_msg VARCHAR2(200);
begin
v_sender := 'abc@xyz.com';
v_recipients := 'aaa@xyz.com';
v_subj := 'Info';
v_msg := 'This is an automated mail';
CALL (UTL_MAIL.SEND(v_sender, v_recipients, NULL, NULL, v_subj, v_msg));
END;
```

and I am receiving an error:

> [Error] Execution (12: 9): ORA-06550: line 12, column 9:
>   PLS-00222: no function with name 'SEND' exists in this scope
>   ORA-06550: line 12, column 3:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Please help me with this..
Thank you

Comment: is this oracle? if yes, pls read this: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_10g_utl_mail.htm

Comment: remove the CALL.  Just have: UTL_MAIL.SEND(v_sender, v_recipients, NULL, NULL, v_subj, v_msg);